# How can I write a test which expects an 'Error' to be thrown in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, testing, node.js, jasmine

I'm trying to write a test for the [Jasmine Test Framework](http://jasmine.github.io/) which expects an error. At the moment I'm using a [Jasmine Node.js integration from GitHub](https://github.com/sconover/jasmine-node).

In my Node.js module I have the following code:

```
throw new Error("Parsing is not possible");
```

Now I try to write a test which expects this error:

```
describe('my suite...', function() {
    [..]
    it('should not parse foo', function() {
    [..]
        expect(parser.parse(raw)).toThrow(new Error("Parsing is not possible"));
    });
});
```

I tried also `Error()` and some other variants and just can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: To pass arguments to the function being tested, without using an anonymous function, try `Function.bind`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13233194/294855

Answer (score 948, accepted):

Try using an anonymous function instead:

```
expect( function(){ parser.parse(raw); } ).toThrow(new Error("Parsing is not possible"));
```

Or using a lambda:

```
expect( () => parser.parse(raw) ).toThrow(new Error("Parsing is not possible"));
```

you should be passing a function into the `expect(...)` call. Your incorrect code:

```
// incorrect:
expect(parser.parse(raw)).toThrow(new Error("Parsing is not possible"));
```

is trying to actually **call** `parser.parse(raw)` in an attempt to pass the result into `expect(...)`,

Comment: If you don't need to pass arguments too, you can also just pass the function to expect: `expect(parser.parse).toThrow(...)`

Comment: Helpful tip:  You can simply call `expect(blah).toThrow()`.  No arguments means check to see that it throws at all.  No string matching required.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9525172/1804678

Comment: In my opinion, it is more obvious as to the intent of the test when wrapping in an anonymous function. Also, it remains consistent among all tests when, for example, you have to pass parameters to the target function to make it throw.

Comment: @SubmittedDenied: This doesn't work in general! If `parser.parse` uses `this`, passing it without context will produce unexpected results. You could pass `parser.parse.bind(parser)`, but honestly... an anonymous function would be more elegant.

Comment: not upvoted because there are 911 votes, but you got my shadow upvote :thumbsup:

Comment: Coming back to this answer for the who knows which time
Thanks again!

Answer (score 91):

You are using:

```
expect(fn).toThrow(e)
```

But if you'll have a look on the function comment (expected is string):

```
294 /**
295  * Matcher that checks that the expected exception was thrown by the actual.
296  *
297  * @param {String} expected
298  */
299 jasmine.Matchers.prototype.toThrow = function(expected) {
```

I suppose you should probably write it like this (using lambda - anonymous function):

```
expect(function() { parser.parse(raw); } ).toThrow("Parsing is not possible");
```

This is confirmed in the following example:

```
expect(function () {throw new Error("Parsing is not possible")}).toThrow("Parsing is not possible");
```

[Douglas Crockford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford) strongly recommends this approach, instead of using "throw new Error()" (prototyping way):

```
throw {
   name: "Error",
   message: "Parsing is not possible"
}
```

Comment: Actually looking at the code toThrow will happily take either an exception object /or/ a string. Check out the calls it is making to expected.message for example.

Comment: It seams to allow string as a side effect of string having no message property

Comment: If you throw an object rather than an Error (as in your example at the bottom), then you won't get a stack trace in the browsers that support it.

Comment: @kybernetikos surprisingly, not entirely true; you'll still get a stack trace printed in the Chrome console if you throw a non-`Error` (http://jsfiddle.net/k1mxey8j/). However, your thrown object of course won't have the `.stack` property, which may be important if you want to set up *automated* error reporting.

Answer (score 38):

As mentioned previously, a function needs to be passed to `toThrow` as it is the function you're describing in your test: "I expect this function to throw x"

```
expect(() => parser.parse(raw))
  .toThrow(new Error('Parsing is not possible'));
```

If using [Jasmine-Matchers](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers#functions-and-errors) you can also use one of the following when they suit the situation;

```
// I just want to know that an error was
// thrown and nothing more about it
expect(() => parser.parse(raw))
  .toThrowAnyError();
```

or

```
// I just want to know that an error of 
// a given type was thrown and nothing more
expect(() => parser.parse(raw))
  .toThrowErrorOfType(TypeError);
```

Comment: It's `expect(foo).toThrowError(TypeError);` in Jasmine 2.5: https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction

Answer (score 31):

A more elegant solution than creating an anonymous function whose sole purpose is to wrap another, is to use [ES5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition)'s [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function. The *bind* function creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Instead of:

`expect(function () { parser.parse(raw, config); } ).toThrow("Parsing is not possible");`

Consider:

`expect(parser.parse.bind(parser, raw, config)).toThrow("Parsing is not possible");`

The *bind* syntax allows you to test functions with different `this` values, and in my opinion makes the test more readable. See also:

*[Does Jasmine's toThrow matcher require the argument to be wrapped in an anonymous function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500586/does-jasmines-tothrow-matcher-require-the-argument-to-be-wrapped-in-an-anonymou/13233194#13233194)*

Answer (score 26):

I replace Jasmine's toThrow matcher with the following, which lets you match on the exception's name property or its message property.  For me this makes tests easier to write and less brittle, as I can do the following:

```
throw {
   name: "NoActionProvided",
   message: "Please specify an 'action' property when configuring the action map."
}
```

and then test with the following:

```
expect (function () {
   .. do something
}).toThrow ("NoActionProvided");
```

This lets me tweak the exception message later without breaking tests, when the important thing is that it threw the expected type of exception.

This is the replacement for toThrow that allows this:

```
jasmine.Matchers.prototype.toThrow = function(expected) {
  var result = false;
  var exception;
  if (typeof this.actual != 'function') {
    throw new Error('Actual is not a function');
  }
  try {
    this.actual();
  } catch (e) {
    exception = e;
  }
  if (exception) {
      result = (expected === jasmine.undefined || this.env.equals_(exception.message || exception, expected.message || expected) || this.env.equals_(exception.name, expected));
  }

  var not = this.isNot ? "not " : "";

  this.message = function() {
    if (exception && (expected === jasmine.undefined || !this.env.equals_(exception.message || exception, expected.message || expected))) {
      return ["Expected function " + not + "to throw", expected ? expected.name || expected.message || expected : " an exception", ", but it threw", exception.name || exception.message || exception].join(' ');
    } else {
      return "Expected function to throw an exception.";
    }
  };

  return result;
};
```

Comment: Really this should be implementing this as a custom matcher with the modern Jasmine library. I did something similar and created a custom matcher called toThrowErrorNamed

Answer (score 12):

I know that is more code, but you can also do:

```
try
    Do something
    @fail Error("should send a Exception")
catch e
    expect(e.name).toBe "BLA_ERROR"
    expect(e.message).toBe 'Message'
```

Answer (score 10):

In my case, the function throwing an error was *async*, so I followed [this](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1410):

```
await expectAsync(asyncFunction()).toBeRejected();
await expectAsync(asyncFunction()).toBeRejectedWithError(...);
```

Answer (score 6):

For [CoffeeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript) lovers:

```
expect( => someMethodCall(arg1, arg2)).toThrow()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
it('it should fail', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);

    try {
        await testInstance.doSomething();
    }
    catch (ex) {
        expect(ex).toBeInstanceOf(MyCustomError);
    }
});
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68732570/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 4):

For me, the posted solution didn't work and it kept on throwing this error:

> Error: Expected function to throw an exception.

I later realised that the function which I was expecting to throw an error was an *async* function and was expecting the promise to be rejected and then throw an error and that's what I was doing in my code:

```
throw new Error('REQUEST ID NOT FOUND');
```

And that’s what I did in my test and it worked:

```
it('Test should throw error if request not found', willResolve(() => {
    const promise = service.getRequestStatus('request-id');
        return expectToReject(promise).then((err) => {
            expect(err.message).toEqual('REQUEST NOT FOUND');
        });
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was very confused, but your comment makes perfect sense. I fixed the issue using the new `expectAsync` https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.3/async-matchers.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem (and this question on Stackoverflow) when was trying to check that async function throws, and found that first answer works great *after* I create a following helper function (below is TypeScript, removing types will give you plain JavaScript):

```
export function toPromise(funcOrPromise: ()=>Promise| Promise): Promise{
  let promise = funcOrPromise instanceOf Promise ? funcOrPromise : funcOrPromise();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => promise.then( r=>resolve(r)).catch(e=>reject(e)));
}
```

To be used as this:

```
asyncExpect(toPromise(asyncFunc)).toBeRejectedWithError(/error text/);
```

or

```
asyncExpect(toPromise(asyncFunc())).toBeRejectedWithError(/error text/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Juan Rada's answer, here is a "poor man's" approach, using only `expect(a).toBe(b)`:

```
it('Throws an error when doing xyz', function() {
  let caughtError = '';
  try {
    xyz();
  } catch (e) {
    caughtError = e.message;
  }
  expect( caughtError ).toBe( 'Parsing is not possible' );
});
```