# Does Jasmine's toThrow matcher require the argument to be wrapped in an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

The documentation at *https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Matchers* includes the following:

```
expect(function(){fn();}).toThrow(e);
```

As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144686/how-to-write-a-test-which-expects-an-error-to-be-thrown), the following does **not** work, because we want to pass a function object to `expect` rather than the result of calling `fn()`:

```
expect(fn()).toThrow(e);
```

Does the following work?

```
expect(fn).toThrow(e);
```

If I've defined an object `thing` with a method `doIt`, does the following work?

```
expect(thing.doIt).toThrow(e);
```

(If so, is there a way to pass arguments to the `doIt` method?)

Empirically the answer seems to be yes, but I don't trust my understanding of JavaScript scoping quite enough to be sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144686/jasmine-how-to-write-a-test-which-expects-an-error-to-be-thrown

Comment: The first link is (effectively) broken as it redirects to [a generic page](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/wiki/).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

We can do away with the anonymous function wrapper by using `Function.bind`, which was introduced in [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf).  This works in the latest versions of browsers, and you can patch older browsers by defining the function yourself. An example definition is given at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Here's an example of how `bind` can be used with Jasmine.

```
describe('using bind with jasmine', function() {

    var f = function(x) {
        if(x === 2) {
            throw new Error();
        }
    }

    it('lets us avoid using an anonymous function', function() {
        expect(f.bind(null, 2)).toThrow();
    });

});
```

The first argument provided to `bind` is used as the `this` variable when `f` is called. Any additional arguments are passed to `f` when it is invoked. Here `2` is being passed as its first and only argument.

Comment: That works for me. Note: remember the null in f.bind( or your parameters will be one off in the called function. I missed that the first time. (I linked to this to make it easier for me to find :http://geekswithblogs.net/Aligned/archive/2013/03/21/use-the-bind-method-for-jasmine-tothrow-tests.aspx) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Let’s take a look at the [Jasmine source code](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v1.3.1/src/core/Matchers.js#L326):

```
try {
  this.actual();
} catch (e) {
  exception = e;
}
if (exception) {
  result = (expected === jasmine.undefined || this.env.equals_(exception.message || exception, expected.message || expected));
}
```

This is the core part of the `toThrow`  method. So all the method does is to execute the method you want to expect and check if a exception was thrown.

So in your examples, `fn` or `thing.doIt` will be called in the Jasmine will check if an error was thrown and if the type of this error is the one you passed into `toThrow` .

Comment: Sadly, it seems that if I need to test a function that takes parameters, then I will need to wrap it with a function.

Comment: Something seems to be missing near *"called in the"* (it is incomprehensible).

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, it seems that if I need to test a function that takes parameters, then I will need to wrap it with a function.

I would rather have preferred,

```
expect(myTestFunction, arg1, arg2).toThrow();
```

But I am ok with explicitly doing

```
expect(function(){myTestFunction(arg1, arg2);}).toThrow("some error");
```

FYI, note that we can also use a regex match on error:

```
expect(function (){myTestFunction(arg1, arg2);}).toThrowError(/err/);
```

Comment: Jasmine 2.0 has toThrowError(/regex/)

Comment: For the record, you can do `expect(() => myTestFunction(arg1, arg2);}).toThrow();`
1. no need for argument in `toThrow`
2. less code, if you can do ES6

Answer (score 5):

If it is used like this:

`expect(myTestFunction(arg)).toThrowAnyError(); // incorrect`

Then the function `myTestFunction(arg)` is executed before `expect(...)` and throw an exception before Jasmine has any chance of doing anything and it crashes the test resulting in an automatic failure.

If the function `myTestFunction(arg)` is not throwing anything (i.e. the code is not working as expected), then Jasmine would only get the **result** of the function and check that for errors - which is incorrect.

To alleviate this, the code that is expected to throw an error is supposed to be wrapped in a function. This is passed to Jasmine which will execute it and check for the expected exception.

`expect(() => myTestFunction(arg)).toThrowAnyError(); // correct`