# Catch error in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

In my code I throw message:

```
var err = new Error();
func1: function(){
        err.name = "error1";  
        throw(err);
    },
```

I tried to catch this error in Jasmine in two options:

```
expect(func1().toThrow("error1");
expect(func1().toThrow(new Error("error1"))
```

The problem that Jasmine failed and don't check this error. Did I miss something ?

Comment: To pass arguments to the function being tested, without using an anonymous function, try `Function.bind`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13233194/294855

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toThrow` matches on the `message` field of the exception.

So, if you change your code to

```
func1: function(){
     err.message = "error1";  
     throw(err);
}
```

You should have more luck