# Angular 4 Jasmine Actual is not a Function

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm doing `expect(ClassUnderTest.someMethod(withSomeParams)).toThrow()` and I'm getting:-

```
Error: <toThrow> : Actual is not a Function
Usage: expect(function() {<expectation>}).toThrow(<ErrorConstructor>, <message>)
```

and I don't understand the usage example.

I tried `expect(() => ClassUnderTest.someMethod(withSomeParams)).toThrow()` I got `Expected function to throw an exception.`. And tried:-

```
ClassUnderTest.someMethod(withSomeParams)
              .subscribe( res => res,
                          err => console.log(err))
```

and I got `Error: 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue.`

I don't understand how to write this expectation for when the error is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the *function itself* into `expect`. The way you have it, you're passing the *result* of `ClassUnderTest.someMethod(withSomeParams)` in.

You are actually doing it correctly in `expect(() => ClassUnderTest.someMethod(withSomeParams)).toThrow()`. The error is either due to an actual error in your implementation, or because of `this` binding with arrow functions.

To fix this, you can try:

```
expect(function () { ClassUnderTest.someMethod(withSomeParams) };).toThrow()
```

or:

```
expect(ClassUnderTest.someMethod.bind(null, withSomeParams)).toThrow()
```

See [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500586/does-jasmines-tothrow-matcher-require-the-argument-to-be-wrapped-in-an-anonymou) and the `.toThrow` section in the [Jasmine docs](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Expectations).