# How can I get Jasmine in CoffeeScript to test for exceptions?

Tags: exception, coffeescript, jasmine

I have this code:

```
class root.Goal
    constructor: (@name, @size) ->
        if @size <= 0 then throw new Error "Goal must be larger than 0 size"
```

Tested by this Jasmine-CoffeeScript test:

```
it "cannot be of size 0", ->
    expect(new p.Goal("Goal 3", 0)).toThrow "Goal must be larger than 0 size"
```

It appears that the exception gets thrown, but not handled by the test:

```
cannot be of size 0
Failures:
  1) cannot be of size 0
   Message:
     Error: Goal must be larger than 0 size
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Goal must be larger than 0 size
    at new Goal (/var/lib/stickshift/1d4f33cd01e442eaa154aed2e7697ca7/app-root/data/235917/prioritization/process.coffee:14:15)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a test which expects an Error to be thrown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144686/how-to-write-a-test-which-expects-an-error-to-be-thrown)

Comment: I thought maybe so too...so I tried to call the "new p.Goal("Goal 3", 0) in an anonymous function, like this: expect(f = do -> new p.Goal("Goal 3", 0)), but that didn't work either.

Comment: turned out this syntax worked:  expect(-> new p.Goal("Goal 3", 0)).toThrow "Goal must be larger than 0 size"

Comment: Right, `expect` wants a function to execute but the `do` would execute the function before `expect` got called.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already found you have to wrap the call to your error-throwing code in an anonymous function. If you dont the call to expect will get the "result" (if any) of your error-throwing code. So when expects gets called all the "action" is already over.