# Jasmine .toThrow error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, bootstrap-modal

I have the following function:

```
function checkforLandP(n){
if(n[0]=== '£' && n[n.length-1] === 'p'){
    // remove the p 
    n =n.slice(0, -1);
    // remove the £
    n = n.substr(1);

    // take the value  and multiply by 100
    n =Math.round(n*100);
    if(isNaN(n)){
        window.alert('Please enter a valid number');
        throw ('Please enter a valid number');
    }
}
return n;
};
```

and the following test:

```
describe("check for £ and p", function(){
  it("checks the array for £ and p together", function(){
    expect(checkforLandP('£234p')).toBe(23400);
    expect(checkforLandP(234)).toBe(234);
    expect(checkforLandP('asdfsdf')).toBe('asdfsdf');
    expect(checkforLandP('£asdfsdfp')).toThrow("Please enter a valid number");
    });
});
```

The test fails and returns: Please enter a valid number thrown

I have been playing with the syntax and almost everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should pass a function that will be executed not the result, you can try this with anonymous function.

```
expect(function() {checkforLandP('£asdfsdfp'); } ).toThrow("Please enter a valid number");
```

See also this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4144803/2419919