# Issues handling Angular error in unit test

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am still coming up to speed on Angular. I searched and found very little. Most helpful was: [How to write a test which expects an Error to be thrown in Jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144686/how-to-write-a-test-which-expects-an-error-to-be-thrown-in-jasmine)

Here is my issue after reading the above post.

I am unit testing a method that throws an error. I want to catch the error so that I know that the unit test was successful. Here is my function call:

```
        expect(function(){instance.selectMember(event);}).toThrow();
```

and the line generating the error:

```
        throw new Error('member not found: ' + member.id);
```

What I got was as follows

```
Expected function to throw an Error.
```

Followed by:

```
Failed: member not found: 42
Error: member not found: 42
```

So it failed because it didn't get an error, but then displayed the error???

I've also tried:

```
        expect(function(){instance.selectMember(event);}).toThrow(new Error('member not found: 42'));
```

and

```
        expect(function(){instance.selectMember(event);}).toThrowError('member not found: 42');
```

with the same results.

How do I know my unit test triggered the error correctly?

Comment: can you post the selectMember() code? Is there any async work done in it?

Comment: @Ismail Ah, async work. Yes. That's the problem. Thanks for the input. Please post as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your method does some async work then you should have your test in a different way, like for example using `fakeAsync` and `tick()` to stub the async.

If you update your question with the method code I can give you more detailed answer.

Comment: Yep. I haven't quite internalized that, I guess. Thanks for pointing it out to me.